# Are there some circumstances that boost::function could not be replaced by std::function?

Tags: c++, boost

Are there some circumstances that `boost::function` could not be replaced by `std::function`?

It would be better if you could give some simple examples.

Comment: A bit too open for a question here, but I like it :)

Comment: What do you mean by replace? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [theboostcpplibraries.com](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.function):

> If you work in a development environment supporting C++11, you have access to the class `std::function` from the header file `<functional>`. In this case you can ignore Boost.Function because `boost::function` and `std::function` are equivalent.

But it might depends of version of boost, see [history](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/function/history.html).